# how can create alphabet sound onclick of image button

Tags: android

I am  developing a kids application. I am using View flipper to slide the images and add two button nest and previousI want when i press A button play sound A and when i press apple button play sound Apple . I have all the image take in  array type int and put into drawable folder.i want to play sound according  to image  alphabet.Please tell me how can create  a kid application with image and sound . i am trying something but crash

```
  private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
 private ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher;
 Button next,pre;
 int[]sound;
 MediaPlayer mp;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image);

     sound= new int[]{R.raw.pack1s1,R.raw.pack1s2,R.raw.pack1s3,R.raw.pack1s4};
     mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.pack1s1);

     int Images[]={R.drawable.pack1d1,R.drawable.pack1d2,R.drawable.pack1d3,R.drawable.pack1d4,R.drawable.pack1d5,R.drawable.pack1d6,
                   R.drawable.pack1d7,R.drawable.pack1d8,R.drawable.pack1d9,R.drawable.pack1d10,R.drawable.pack1d11,R.drawable.pack1d12,
                   R.drawable.pack1d13,R.drawable.pack1d14,R.drawable.pack1d15,R.drawable.pack1d16,
                   R.drawable.pack1d17,R.drawable.pack1d18,R.drawable.pack1d19,R.drawable.pack1d20,R.drawable.pack1d21,R.drawable.pack1d22,
                   R.drawable.pack1d23,R.drawable.pack1d24,R.drawable.pack1d25,R.drawable.pack1d26};

    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
    next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    pre=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    pre.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          viewFlipper.showPrevious();

        }
    });
    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            viewFlipper.showNext();
        }
    });

     for(int i=0;i<Images.length;i++)
            {
                setFlipperImage(Images[i]);
            }
```

}

```
        private void setFlipperImage(int res)
        {
                Log.i("Set Filpper Called", res+"");
                ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                image.setBackgroundResource(res);
                viewFlipper.addView(image);     
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Create a class like

```
public class SoundCard{

 private int imageRes;
 private int soundRes;
 //A constructor maybe...
 //Getters & Setters...

}
```

then use it in array like you did for images:

```
SoundCard [] soundCards=new SoundCard[]{new SoundCard(image,sound),...}
```

and use it in your `ViewFlipper`